# SVG issues in ie11

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a div that has it's height set to 320 pixels, then it's child is set to 100% width of that.
The child of that is a SVG file which I set the width to 200% of the container.
In chrome and firefox that works fine, I get a nice image like this:

[image]

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="kit-template ng-isolate-scope front">
    <div class="svg-document ng-scope">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 259.5 131.4" enable-background="new 0 0 259.5 131.4" xml:space="preserve" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- Removed for brevity -->
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS/SASS looks like this:

```
.kit-template {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;   
    height: 320px;

    .svg-document {  
        width: 100%;   
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;*/

        svg {
            width: 200%;

            path, polyline, polygon, rect {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, this works fine in both Chrome, Firefox and IE Edge. But in IE11 I get this:

[image]

And if I inspect the element, I can see that the SVG looks like it has padding left and right on it, but I can assure you it doesn't.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

**Update 1**

I have created a very simple version on codepen so you can see the issue.
Here it is:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/Kdypwe

View that in chrome, firefox, Edge and then IE11. You will see that only IE11 has the issue.

Comment: Why is your SVG set to a width of 200%?

Comment: because it has a front and a back and I only want to see the front

Comment: We need to see how you have your image included in your SVG tag. So we can see your code in context. Also a code example would be even better so we can test your code in a live editable environment like codepen or jsfiddle. We need more context regarding your image so we can help you!

Comment: I will have a go at doing this, might take me a while to strip out the stuff that isn't necessary.

Comment: I have added a codepen to illustrate my issue.

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo any ideas?

Comment: Just made my Answer, check below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you can do is add the `height="320"` attribute to your SVG tag. So IE can render correctly. I believe IE11 is thrown off by using width 200% in your CSS. But since `xml:space="preserve"` is the default, setting only the height will keep the proportions of your SVG jacket.

Test codepen example in IE11:

http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/MarvEm

```
<svg height="320" viewBox="0 0 248.2 142.8" enable-background="new 0 0 248.2 142.8" xml:space="preserve">
```

Also remove the XML namespace tag since it is not needed inside an HTML page. And you can also remove some of the SVG attributes like `version`, `xmlns`, `xmlns:xlink`, `x`, and `y`, since those are not needed as well.

Comment: I just want to add a comment to this:
IE11 will fix the issue if you apply a height, by default IE11 assumes all SVGs to be 150px high unless otherwise specified. There is another solution though, you can actually set the width of the SVG to 100% and it will resize although that doesn't actually fix my issue. In the end, I didn't use a height or width. I created a directive that read the viewBox attribute and worked out the height / width by the difference in the container width vs the viewBox width.

Comment: IE11 made my SVG 150px height for no apparent reason.

Comment: `150px` is the default for `<svg>` elements in IE11 if `height` is not set.. So you need to set a specific height in your CSS or inline via `height` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I was having SVG image display issue in IE11. The issue was inner svg image was having width and height mentioned. Due to this it was failing to scale properly on IE11 and it was working fine on IE edge, chrome, firefox very fine.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
```

To fix the issue I removed width="120" height="120" and its working fine.
When I observed svg image was having **width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"** but in IE11 it was only showing **width="120" height="120"**.

output was:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120">
```

[image]