# css transform not working with IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Im using transform to center a carrot for a dropdown menu and its working perfectly on every browser except IE

HTML

```
<div class="row ccu-faq-q-row">
  <div class="ccu-faq-question">I’m not crazy about the new name. And I resent all the money --- has spent on naming the ----. How can I register my protest?</div>
  <div class="ccu-faq-btn"><img class="faqArrow" src="img/ic-arrow.svg"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.ccu-faqs .ccu-faq-btn img {
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  width: 24px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-box-shadow: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? That would help us debug your issue.

Comment: @mfluehr dont i added some html markup

Comment: Just a guess, but possibly there's something wrong with your SVG. (See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33241394/3469273.) IE can be very picky about SVG files.If that doesn't help, can you update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?